# Can Firebase RemoteConfig be accessed from cloud functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-remote-config

I'm using Firebase as a simple game-server and have some settings that are relevant for both client and backend and would like to keep them in RemoteConfig for consistency, but not sure if I can access it from my cloud functions in a simple way (I don't consider going through the REST interface a "simple" way)

As far as I can tell there is no mention of it in the docs, so I guess it's not possible, but does anyone know for sure?

Comment: Did you made a Function to access RemoteConfig using the REST interface you can share with us?

Comment: No, sorry. I decided it wasn't worth the effort for a few variables so decided to just replicate them instead.

Answer (score 9):

*firebaser here*

There is a public [REST API that allows you to read and set Firebase Remote Config conditions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/use-config-rest). This API requires that you have full administrative access to the Firebase project, so must only be used on a trusted environment (such as your development machine, a server you control or Cloud Functions).

There is no public API to get Firebase Remote Config settings from a client environment at the moment. Sorry I don't have better news.

Comment: The REST API that was introduced recently should be accessible from Cloud Functions, right? What would also be interesting: Do you need the Blaze plan to access that API?

Comment: Good point on the new REST API. I updated my answer. This REST API is available in projects on any plan. If you're having problems, post a question with the [minimal steps that reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen This answer is over 4 years old, so I thought I'd just poke in case something has changed.

Comment: Not that I know of, but if it exists it'd be mentioned here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config

Answer (score 4):

This is probably only included in newer versions of firebase (8th or 9th and above if I'm not mistaken).

```js
// We first need to import remoteConfig function.
import { remoteConfig } from firebase-admin

// Then in your cloud function we use it to fetch our remote config values.
const remoteConfigTemplate = await remoteConfig().getTemplate().catch(e => {
 // Your error handling if fetching fails... 
}

// Next it is just matter of extracting the values, which is kinda convoluted, 
// let's say you want to extract `game_version` field from remote config:
const gameVersion = remoteConfigTemplate.parameters.game_version.defaultValue.value
```

So `parameters` are always followed by the name of the field that you defined in Firebase console's remote config, in this example `game_version`.
It's a mouthful (or typeful) but that's how you get it.

Also note that if value is stored as JSON string, you will need to parse it before usage, commonly: `JSON.parse(gameVersion)`.

Similar process is outlined in [Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/automate-rc).